# Where to find pstreams-devel package for Rocky Linux 8 (EPEL)?

Tags: package-management, repository, dnf

It seems there is no pstreams-devel package in Rocky Linux 8. I was wondering why it has not been included and if there is a way to get it from some extra repository?
The last reference to it that I found (from rpmfind.net) refers to EPEL 7 so it seems it did not make it to version 8, while a recent version seems to be available on Fedora 36, any idea why not on EPEL 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> while a recent version seems to be available on Fedora 36, any idea why not on EPEL 8?

The package is now also [retired](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/pstreams-devel/c/832f4f52e8d3c1d34d038ae5ba2bac617aba9aa6?branch=rawhide) from Fedora so Fedora 36 will be the latest Fedora to include it unless someone volunteers as a new maintainer. That's also probably answer for the question why it isn't available in EPEL -- if it wasn't maintained in Fedora, nobody added it to EPEL.

If you need `pstreams-devel` on Rocky 8, you need to install it manually from [source](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/download/#latest).